# CSS properties not loading in order

Tags: css, forms, submit

Are there any specific rules for things such as `input[type="submit"]`?  I'm having trouble with the CSS properties being loaded in a seemingly incorrect order.

On line 400 of my CSS style sheet I have the following:

```
input[type="submit"] {
margin: 5px;
}
```

This is the standard setting for Submit buttons.  However, I have a particular submit button that I'd like to style differently, which is on line 800 of my CSS style sheet and so I would have thought it would overwrite the previous style:

```
.inputSubmit {
margin: 0;
margin-left: 5px;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 18px;
vertical-align: middle;
color: #555555;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;">
<form method="get" name="search">
<input type="text" name="searchBox" class='inputText'>
<input type="submit" value="search" class='inputSubmit'>
</form>
</div>
```

When the page loads, the Submit button loads all of the styles for `inputSubmit` except the `margin` settings, which when I inspect the element in Chrome I can see as being crossed out in favour of the earlier style.  This has thrown my understanding of CSS out of the window, because I thought it worked in order - and always has in every situation in the past.

For example, I can set `h6 {margin: 5px;}` and `.h6Test {margin: 0px; }` in that order, and all browsers still recognise the "class" was assigned afterwards and overwrite the default margin for any `<h6 class="h6Test">` tags.

I can force the styles to take effect applying `input[type="submit"].inputSubmit`, so I have achieved the result I need, but I don't understand why I've had to do that.  This is what makes me think this is a "Special" type of property that for some reason operates outside of the boundaries of normal CSS.

Can anyone shed any light on it please?

Comment: *“...but I don't understand why I've had to do that.”* - it's called selector specificity: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the selector `input[type="submit"]` has higher specificity than the selector `.inputSubmit`. The rule with more specific selector “wins”. This has nothing to do with loading order.

By the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) rules (a key part of CSS, Cascading Style Sheets, yet misunderstood by most people), `input[type="submit"]` has specificity 0,0,1,1 (one attribute selector, one element selector), whereas `.inputSubmit` has specificity 0,0,1,0 (just one class selector, counted as an attribute selector). Using `input[type="submit"].inputSubmit` you get specificity 0,0,2,1, which is fine. Actually, `[type="submit"].inputSubmit` would suffice (specificity 0,0,2,0).

Comment: This is a really good explanation, thanks, I have changed my accepted answer to this

Answer (score 0):

**ID selectors have a higher specificity than attribute selectors.**

For example, in HTML, the selector #p123 is more specific than [id=p123] in terms of the cascade.

```
A:
a#a-02 { background-image : url(n.gif); }

and

B:
a[id="a-02"] { background-image : url(n.png); }
```

the first rule (A) is more specific than the second one (B). [W3C CSS 2.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html)

Comment: The code in the question has no ID selector (and no `id` attribute).